# Deploying jhipster application on Digital Ocean

Tags: jhipster

I am looking to use Digital Ocean services to host cloud apps.
Can anyone share information on deployment of jhipster apps on Digital Ocean ? 
Any setup tips or steps to watch out ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker module to build jhip docker containers...

More on:
https://jhipster.github.io/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-docker

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install JAVA with following command (for example JAVA 8):
   `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`
2. Install DB (Mysql/Postgre etc which you're using), Create database and user
3. Uploading `.jar` file
4. Run the application

For more [details](https://blog.rimon.xyz/2017/09/deploy-spring-boot-app-in-digitalocean.html).

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877

Comment: I think you have already got the solution. Your preferred port (port 5000) needed to be allowed. Happy coding!

Comment: Yes, Thanks anyway