# Unable to access my website using the IP address of my Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: deployment, backend, web-deployment, digital-ocean, mern

I am in the process of deploying my MERN app to a Digital Ocean droplet(Ubuntu 20.04 server).

I have cloned my GitHub repo, installed the dependencies and pm2.

I start the server using the command `pm2 start server/index.js`.
[image]
Then when I visit the URL `http://134.122.112.22:5000`, I get the following error:
[image]
Why am I not able to access my site?

**Note that I have not yet bought a domain. Also I have not yet installed NGINX.*

Am I missing something?

**EDIT-1**
I added a HTTP inbound rule in the firewall. Yet, I am receiving the same error.
[image]

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/firewalls/how-to/configure-rules/

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar I added an HTTP inbound rule in the firewall. (Pls. see the edit in the question). Yet, when I visit `http://134.122.112.22` I receive the same error - This site can't be reached. Do I need to add any other inbound rule?

Comment: add an inbound rule for port 5000 and test.

Comment: No, still getting the same error. I don't understand why are these things so complicated.

Comment: you are missing the nginx your port is 80 is open but you are trying 5000 so wont work. you can open the 5000 in firewall and also check ufw firewall.ufw status and open the port `sudo ufw allow 5000 `

Comment: @HarshManvar Finally....It worked. Thanks a ton.

Comment: @HKS Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the **Nginx**. Port **80** is open but you are trying **5000**, so won't work.

You can open port **5000** in the firewall and also check **ufw** firewall.

```
ufw status
```

and open the port using command

```
sudo ufw allow 5000
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66967621/9409877